# Mongo db string based range query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a model name **product** which has a key  `ageGroup: ["10 - 12", "13 - 15"]` array of range strings

I need to query all the elements if i pass the ageGroup 10 or 11 or 15 in number or in string.

For ex

```
db.product.find({ageGroup: 11})
```

Or

```
db.product.find({ageGroup: 15})
```

Sorry for bad question typing, using mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have predefined list of strings of ranges. You can find the range first from that list, outside MongoDB, then use that string to query. The implementation will depend on the language you are using.

If you don't have that information in advance. You can use `$map`, `$split`, `$toInt`, `$arrayToObject` in [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) to convert `["10 - 12", "13 - 15"]` to something like `[{ "from": 10, "to": 12 }, { "from": 13, "to": 15 }]` which will be easier to filter.

Comment: thanks for your help, using array of objects helped alot. But in my case there was no need to save array of objects in db. I did it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are saving this in same format then you can use substr aggregated query to extract data.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/